# Upload website in a rented cloud server

Tags: domain, hosting, website, upload, html

I have access to a cloud server by IONOS. My domain has been connected to this server. Now the next step is to create a website and upload it. I have no experience in doing that. I use FileZilla to connect on the server and transfer the files. But I have no idea where I should save the html files etc. Any help would be really appreciated. Thank you in advance and happy new year.

Comment: Welcome to ServerFault. Unfortunately, we don't know the answer since it depends on your hosting. You'll need to ask your hosting provider. This is the most basic thing their customers need to know, so you can probably find it in their documentation or FAQ. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you Andrew, I have checked the documentation etc I cannot find anything related. I will ask them directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

usually  it's .../www/html or something similar *but check your web server application and/or OS docs for the entire path*.

This does mean you do need some form of web server like Apache or what not. For static sites you can do away with Caddy or what not though. Which may be easier to cope with.

Comment: Right, forgot that I needed to install Aapche :O 
Thank you very much , happy new year.

Comment: You are very welcome and awww thanks! Don't forget to then in this case mark this answer as the one that fixed your issue and so on. :)